# what that is error mean when i building gradle?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, sdk

[image: aidl is missing from sdk/build-tools/27.03/aidl.exe]

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':multidimens:compileDebugAidl'.

  > java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from 'F:\Apps\android studio\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Comment: Have you run the **--stacktrace** command? What is the **stacktrace** ?

Comment: i can not understand what is meaning about "stacktrace" !

Comment: Run this command and see what are you getting.                                _./gradlew build --stacktrace_

Comment: '/gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Dot (.) is missing in the command.

Comment: Can u write full command ?